# Что нужно для нормальной работы собственного глобального сервера?

Tags: c++, qt, сервер, сеть

Что нужно для нормальной работы собственного глобального сервера?.
Хочу поднять свой сервер из дома , какие заморочки меня ждут?

```
#include "Server.h"
Server::Server(){//Server user-defined constructor

}

Server::~Server(){//Server default destructor

}

void Server::startServer(){//called when server starts working
    qDebug()<< "Stex"<<'\n';
    if (this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 80)){
        qDebug()<< "LISTENING!!"<<'\n';
    }
    else qDebug()<< "NOt Listening"<<'\n';
}

void Server::BackUP(){
    ofstream BackUp("C:\\Users\\НеВажно\\Documents\\BDServer\\BackUp.txt");
    system("cls");
    BackUp << showRecentClients().toStdString();

}
Server::CLIENT::CLIENT(QString name){
    ::userSerialNumber ++;
    selfSerialNumber = :: userSerialNumber;
    this->name = name;
}
Server::CLIENT::~CLIENT(){

}

QString Server::CLIENT::ShowConditions(){//defining show condition of current socket

    return +"|Client N  :"    +QString::number(this->selfSerialNumber)
           +"   |TOKEN  :"    +this->TOKEN
           +"   |STATUS :"    +(this->STATUS == false ? "NOT CONNECTED" : "CONNECTED")
           +"   |IP_v4  :"    +(this->IP_v4.toString())
           +"   |PERMISSION :"+(this->Permission);

}

QString Server::showRecentClients(){//show  conditions of recent connected clients
    QString MAINSTRING;
    qDebug()<< "\n\n_______RECENT_____CLIENTS_____";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < CLIENTSet.size(); ++i){
        qDebug() << CLIENTSet[i].ShowConditions();
        MAINSTRING +=( CLIENTSet[i].ShowConditions() + '\n');
    }
      qDebug()<< "_______RECENT_____CLIENTS_____\n\n";
      return MAINSTRING;
}

void Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){                                      //called when incoming signal from 5555 port detected

    CLIENT *newCLIENT = new CLIENT();                                                       //create new client
    newCLIENT->selfSerialNumber = userSerialNumber;                                         //set new client serial number
    newCLIENT->socket = new QTcpSocket(this);                                               //create new socket for new client
    CLIENTSet.push_back(*newCLIENT);                                                        //add new client to recent clients set   <CLIENTSet>
    newCLIENT->socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);                               //.........................................
    connect(newCLIENT->socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(sockReady()));                 //bind function readyRead() with sockReady()
    connect(newCLIENT->socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(sockDisc()));               //bind funtcion disconnected() with sockDisc()
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].STATUS =  CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].socket->isOpen(); //set new client status wether it open or not
    if ( CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].socket->isOpen()){
        qDebug() << "New Connection ... ";
    }

}

void Server::sockReady(){//called when sockt is ready to send/recieve Bytes
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].TOKEN = CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].socket->readAll();//get Token from client
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].IP_v4 = CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].socket->peerAddress();//get IP_v4 address from client
    if (CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
        CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].TOKEN = DEFAULT;
        qDebug() << "TOKEN IS EMPTY\n";
    }
    if (CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].TOKEN == this->rootTOKEN)
          CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].Permission = Zero;//if token ,sended from client , is equal to rootTOKEN , give client ROOT (Zero) Permission

    else if (CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].TOKEN == this->userTOKEN)//if token ,sended from client , is equal to userTOKEN , give client USER (One) Permission
          CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].Permission = One;

    else CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].Permission = Two;//if given token is not equal given above tokens give client guest permission
}


void Server::sockDisc(){//called when socket disconnects from slot
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].socket->close();//close socket to ac
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].STATUS  = false;
    CLIENTSet[CLIENTSet.size()-1].ShowConditions();//show condidition of the last connected client
    BackUP();//backup all recent connected clients when the last client disconnected
}
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Что значит "для нормальной работы"? Приведите ваш код, посмотрим, какие могут быть проблемы. Так непонятно даже, что ваш сервер должен делать и на какую нагрузку рассчитан

Comment: Как минимум вам нужен проброс портов (если у вас "серый" IP адрес). Если вы укажете свой "серый" (локальный) IP адрес - к вашему серверу можно будет подключится только из локальной сети. Вам нужен "белый" и статический адрес (чтобы постоянно не менять конфигурацию подключения). Такой адрес стоит, в среднем, 150 - 200 р/месяц. Ну и конечно средний пк. (В зависимости  от задач может подойти обычный, не серверный пк).

Comment: Я прикрепил исходник сервера. Она работает исправно только когда и сервер и клиент запущены на одной машине. По локальной сети не подключается .
В чем проблема не знаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [TCP/IP Client-Server приложение на платформе QtCreator(C++)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157113/tcp-ip-client-server-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-qtcreatorc)

Comment: Я тут другое спросил

Comment: Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону `NAS` сервера, а точнее его реализации. [Пример реализации](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ITqQ0QtsBE), по-сути это файловый сервер, но переделать на другой лад не составит труда.

Comment: @MoloF тут вопрос по программированию, насколько я понял

Comment: @dIm0n в тегах или в самом вопросе я не увидел какой-либо конкретики по языку программирования, поэтому ссылаясь на свой опыт в встрече таких вопросов я дал соответствующее напутствие. Автор по всему хочет поднять локальную машину в интернет, расписывать подробно не вижу смысла, для начала необходимо понять теорию, данную теорию можно получить по ссылке что я указал, либо по другим видео с данным названием. Я смотрел ролики на эту тему и там внятно объясняется как вытащить машину в глобальную сеть и получать доступ к ней там, где есть интернет, а файловый сервер не будет отличаться от обычного

Comment: @MoloF эти теги были, просто их удалили, потому что не было кода, а теперь код появился :) Посмотрите историю изменений

Comment: @MoloF кстати, не советую смотреть ролики на ютубе по теме программирования/администрирования, особенно на русском языке. Лучше читать книги/stackoverflow/доки/стандарты

Comment: @dIm0n почему вы так категоричны по поводу `youtube` и русскоязычного комьюнити?  Я сам учился и администрированию и программированию по роликам, получая какую-то теорию, а дальше смотрел в документацию и тренировался. Я хорошо отношусь к людям которые трудятся и предоставляют бесплатно информацию, главное для себя ее обработать и вынести полезный результат.

Comment: @MoloF в том то и дело, что когда учишься ты не знаешь, а правду тебе рассказывают или нет? Когда ты читаешь книгу, прошедшую множество редакций, а уж тем более стандарт или документацию, то почти всегда ты можешь ей доверять, что часто не так с роликами на ютубе. А про язык роликов это к тому, что англоязычных разработчиков гораздо больше и шанс, что найдут ошибки в таких роликах, больше поэтому

Comment: По моему сервер лучше поднимать не на плюсах. Сам сейчас разбираюсь с qt, и бек было решено писать на java. Если поднимать сервер из дома, то по любому нужно будет договорится с провайдером и получить белый ip, далее пробросить на роутере необходимые порты и уже настраивать сам сервер. Также дела в настройках роутера закрепить адрес пк на котором будет расположен сервер, если это необходимо.